# How to make a menu with a submenu in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to do a menu that might have submenus for some of its options.

The behavior i want it to have is the same we see on most of websites.

When we hover an option that has a submenu, that submenu it will happear, if the mouse arrow goes anywhere else that is not the submenu the submenu will close.

I'm going to illustrate with images.

When we enter the submenu we have this:

[image]

Now we hover the Language option its submenu will happear

[image]

Now what is not done is the behavior i want. If we are hovering on the `Language`option the submenu is visible. If i go directly from `language` to the language's submenu it will remain there as intented.

The code of this example is provided below:

`main.qml`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 500
    title: qsTr("Tabbars")
    Button{
        id: button
        text: "Menu"
        onClicked: contextMenu.open()
        anchors.top:parent.top
        anchors.left:parent.left
        height: 20
        width: 100
    }
    Menu {
        id: contextMenu
        y: button.height
        padding: 1
        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 200
            border.color: "#fff"
            color: "#000"
        }
        Button {
            id: languageMenuItem
            text: qsTr("Language")
            width:parent.width
            height: 35
            background: Item {
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "#555"
                    opacity: mouseArea1.pressed ? 1 : mouseArea1.containsMouse ? 0.6 : 0.0
                    MouseArea {
                        id: mouseArea1
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        hoverEnabled: true
                        onEntered: function() {
                            submenuLanguage.open()
                        }
                        onExited: function() {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            contentItem: Text {
                text: languageMenuItem.text
                color: "#fff"
                font.pointSize: 12
                font.bold: true
            }
            Rectangle {
                z: 1
                color: "#000"
                opacity: 0.5
                anchors.fill: parent
                visible: !parent.enabled
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                mouseArea1.clicked.connect(clicked)
            }
        }
        CMenuItem{
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            width: parent.width
            onClicked: close()
        }
    }
    Menu {
        id:submenuLanguage
        x: contextMenu.width
        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 200
            border.color: "#fff"
            color: "#000"
        }
        Connections {
            target: mouseArea1
            onExited: {
                console.log("mouseArea leaving")
            }
        }
        CMenuItem{
            id:btlingen
            width: parent.width
            text: qsTr("English")
            onClicked: {
                contextMenu.close()
                console.log("English")
            }
        }
        CMenuItem{
            id:btlingpt
            width: parent.width
            text: qsTr("Português")
            onClicked: {
                contextMenu.close()
                console.log("Português")
            }
        }
        CMenuItem{
            id:btlinges
            width: parent.width
            text: qsTr("Español")
            onClicked: {
                contextMenu.close()
                console.log("Español")
            }
        }
        CMenuItem{
            id:btlingit
            width: parent.width
            text: qsTr("Italiano")
            onClicked: {
                contextMenu.close()
                console.log("Italiano")
            }
        }
        CMenuItem{
            id:btlingde
            width: parent.width
            text: qsTr("Deutsch")
            onClicked: {
                contextMenu.close()
                console.log("Deutsch")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`CMenuItem.qml`

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
    import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

    MenuItem {
        id: mainMenuItem
        background: Item {
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "#555"
                opacity: mouseArea.pressed ? 1 : mouseArea.containsMouse ? 0.6 : 0.0
                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                }
            }
        }
        contentItem: Text {


text: mainMenuItem.text
        color: "#fff"
        font.pointSize: 12
        font.bold: true
    }
    Rectangle {
        z: 1
        color: "#000"
        opacity: 0.5
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: !parent.enabled
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        mouseArea.clicked.connect(clicked)
    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cascade](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html#cascade-prop) property to create a nested menu:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 320
    height: 260
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Foo")
            Menu {
                cascade: true  // Nested menu
                title: qsTr("&Bar")
                Action { text: qsTr("A1") }
                Action { text: qsTr("A2") }
                Action { text: qsTr("A3") }
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: IS there a way to style the title on the parent ```Menu```?